# JavaFX displaying resultset into existing tableview

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I am trying to compare HIVE and Oracle table data using a desktop GUI application, so I used JavaFX and built the app, am able to get the user entered data from the forms and execute it in backend and get the resultset however 
I am not able to print the result set in the ResultSet tab of the application
I have tried the methods used [here](http://blog.ngopal.com.np/2011/10/19/dyanmic-tableview-data-from-database/) and browsed few other stack questions but as am new to JFX am not able to get how to print a result set into the scene

[image]

FXML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<TabPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="800.0" prefWidth="1100.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40"
fx:controller="application.Controller">
<tabs>
<Tab text="Query Tab">
  <content>
    <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
           <children>
              <TextArea layoutX="34.0" layoutY="143.0" prefHeight="506.0" prefWidth="360.0" promptText="Hive Query" fx:id="HiveQuery" />
              <TextArea layoutX="506.0" layoutY="141.0" prefHeight="508.0" prefWidth="384.0" promptText="Oracle Query" fx:id="OracleQuery" />
              <TextField layoutX="34.0" layoutY="27.0" promptText="Hive Server Name" fx:id="HiveServerName" />
              <TextField layoutX="34.0" layoutY="79.0" promptText="Hive Username" fx:id="HiveUserName" />
              <PasswordField layoutX="204.0" layoutY="79.0" promptText="Hive Password" fx:id="HivePassword" />
              <PasswordField layoutX="698.0" layoutY="79.0" promptText="Oracle Password" fx:id="OraclePassword" />
              <TextField layoutX="521.0" layoutY="79.0" promptText="Oracle Username" fx:id="OracleUserName" />
              <TextField layoutX="521.0" layoutY="27.0" promptText="Oracle HostName" fx:id="OracleHostName" />
              <Button layoutX="420.0" layoutY="666.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Compare" fx:id="CompareButton" onAction="#CompareDataSets" />
           </children></AnchorPane>
  </content>
</Tab>
<Tab text="Result Set">
  <content>
    <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
           <children>
              <TableView layoutX="8.0" layoutY="19.0" prefHeight="671.0" prefWidth="433.0">
                <columns>
                  <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="C1" />
                  <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="C2" />
                </columns>
              </TableView>
              <TableView layoutX="463.0" layoutY="19.0" prefHeight="671.0" prefWidth="448.0">
                <columns>
                  <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="C1" />
                  <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="C2" />
                </columns>
              </TableView>
           </children></AnchorPane>
  </content>
</Tab>
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried to display your data? The code you posted is just the layout.

Comment: @James_D: Yes, following the link mentioned above I created a separate class and passed the login values to one more class which returns the resultset from oracle and hive... However a new stage/window opens instead of printing in this tab (the table can have any number of columns)

Comment: I guess I need to give a id to table view in fxml and use that in controller but since my table is not of fixed columns I am not exactly sure how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the example you linked to above you can perform the same logic, with a few minor tweaks....  First name your tableView in the FXML, and second, remove the columns that are present so that you only have the tableView.

```
<Tab text="Result Set">
  <content>
    <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
           <children>
              <TableView fx:id="tableView" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="19.0" prefHeight="671.0" prefWidth="433.0">
                <columns>
                </columns>
              </TableView>
              ......
           </children></AnchorPane>
  </content>
</Tab>
```

Then update your controller:

```
//Name your table view in your FXML file and wire it like this.
@FXML
private TableView tableview;

//Then in your method where you process the data you can add columns dynamically....
        /**********************************
         * TABLE COLUMN ADDED DYNAMICALLY *
         **********************************/
        for(int i=0 ; i<rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++){
            //We are using non property style for making dynamic table
            final int j = i;                
            TableColumn col = new TableColumn(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i+1));
            col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<ObservableList,String>,ObservableValue<String>>(){                    
                public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) {                                                                                              
                    return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString());                        
                }                    
            });

            tableview.getColumns().addAll(col); 
            System.out.println("Column ["+i+"] ");
        }

//Etc....
```

This is how you can add your columns dynamically to the tableview laid out in the FXML.

Comment: now I am able to see the table headers in the required place but there are two issues now:
1. All columns are not printed, tableview does not become scrollable instead if I increase the window size and run again more columns are visible.
2. After headers no rows are printed NPE is throw:

Trying to compare data.... 
Column [0] 
... 
Column [21] 
Row [1] added [100777073, null, null, Y, ...]
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at application.Controller$1.call(Controller.java:86)
 at application.Controller$1.call(Controller.java:1)

Comment: return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString()); is the 86th line in the controller

Comment: Check to make sure the value you are returning isn't null..  perhaps something like if (param.getValue().get(j).toString()) != null then 
 return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString());  else return SimpleStringProperty("");   Another trick I have learned is to force the table to repaint if things aren't displayed correctly.  I have at times had to set a column invisible and then visible again.  tableColumn.setVisible(false); tableColumn.setVisible(true);  This can correct a visual display issue.

Comment: Sorry - the if statement would be this:  if (param.getValue().get(j)) != null) -- we can't call toString() on a null reference.

Comment: Yaa... You are right... That row does have null... Can we substitute null as blank instead of ignoring it?

Comment: See my comment above.  Check for null and if it's null then  return new SimpleStringProperty(""); else return what you are returning now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99840/discussion-between-purring-pigeon-and-vinod).